# How to generate a dictionary of methods of a class instance

Tags: python

I have a requirement where i want to map the class's stringified method names to methods with their instance. Right now i am doing it manually. And i am needing this at many more places. What i want is a function with one parameter as a class instance which generates me this dictionary when i run the script.

```
class MyClass:
    def myFunc1(self,param1):
        pass
    def myFunc2(self,param2):
        pass

mycls = MyClass()

# a method that generates me a dict of method names as stringified method names and methods with instance as values
my_class_method_dict = my_method_generator(mycls)

print(my_class_method_dict)
# prints -> {'myFunc1':mycls.myFunc1,'myFunc2':mycls.myFunc2}
# this dict is hard coded right now 


I need it like this because i need to call these instance methods doing something like this
x = my_class_method_dict['myFunc1']()
```

what i have tried:

```
def my_method_generator(cls):
    return {str(method):method for method in dir(cls) if not method.startswith("__")}

# this returns {'myFunc1':mycls.myFunc1,'myFunc2':mycls.myFunc2}

and when i try this (i know obviously wrong):
def my_method_generator(cls):
    return {str(method):cls.method for method in dir(cls) if not method.startswith("__")}
# this returns AttributeError: 'cls' object has no attribute 'method'
```

I tried to look for a solution but not getting any. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. The reason is `dir()` returns a list of strings of the methods, not the actual method objects, so one way to fix this is using the `getattr` given the class and the method name to get the method object.

```py
def my_method_generator(cls):
    return {method: getattr(cls, method) for method in dir(cls) if not method.startswith("__")}
```

Comment: why not `{m_name: method for m_name, method in dir(cls).items() if not m_name.startswith("__")}`?

Comment: @Aaron because `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'` - the `dir()` function returns a list of strings

Comment: my bad... confused with `__dict__` shoulda looked